# Building distribution packages of python application

Tags: python, rpm

Please, help about the proper way to build distribution packages of python application. Firstly i'm interesting about RHEL systems (6/7). By default there are python versions 2.6 and 2.7 installed in /usr/lib. The problem is that I use Ubuntu for build packages where the python installed in /usr/local/lib. The path to the python, used for building, is hardcoded into the package. I didn't find any variants to change it. I tried bdist_rpm, fpm, rpmbuild. The Prefix tag in SPEC file don't work. Should I build packages for RHEL on RHEL systems? Is there any solutions to build packages for different platforms, versions of python, architectures on single machine?

Here is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup 
from cecsagent import globals 
setup( name=globals.APP_NAME, 
       version=globals.APP_VERSION, 
       description="CECS agent", 
       author="...", 
       author_email="...", 
       packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.web.*", "test"]), 
       package_data={"": ["*.xml", "*.template"]}, 
       scripts=["cecs-agent"], 
       install_requires=globals.REQUIRED_LIBS )
```

Comment: "The path to the python, used for building, is hardcoded into the package." Don't do that.  Problem solved.

Comment: Are you using Setuptools?  If so, can we see your `setup.py` file?

Comment: @jgritty "Don't do that. Problem solved"  It's not me, that's the problem.

@Kevin "can we see your setup.py file?"

`from setuptools import find_packages, setup

from cecsagent import globals



setup(
    name=globals.APP_NAME,
    version=globals.APP_VERSION,
    description="CECS agent",
    author="...",
    author_email="...",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.web.*", "test"]),
    package_data={"": ["*.xml", "*.template"]},
    scripts=["cecs-agent"],
    install_requires=globals.REQUIRED_LIBS
)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format code inside a comment)

Comment: Just edit the original question.